# Mongodb standalone , listen to CRUD events

Tags: mongodb

I am using standalone Mongodb and want to listen to any CRUD operation performed ,whether by code or done manually in mongo by console/GUI.

I was looking into change stream and mongo stitch , but change streams and mongo stitch are not provided in standalone Mongodb.

It is any event raising mechanism provided in standalone mongodb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your standalone MongoDB to a single node replica set. In this case, you will still be running with the single MongoDB instance, but instead of running it as standalone you will be running it as a replica set.

1. Shut down the standalone mongod instance.
2. Restart the instance. Use the --replSet option to specify the name of the new replica set. For example, the following command starts a standalone instance as a member of a new replica set named rs0.

   `mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /srv/mongodb/db0 --replSet rs0`
3. Connect a mongo shell to the mongod instance. After connecting run the following command to initiate a replica set.

   `rs.initiate()`

Now, you will be able to make use of the change stream functionality.